# Problem when importing table from pdf to python using tabula

Tags: python-3.x, tabula

When importing data from pdf using tabula with Python, in some cases, I obtain two or more columns merged in one. It does not happen with all the files obtained from the same pdf.

In this case, this is the code used to read the pdf:

> ```
> from tabula import wrapper
>
> tables = wrapper.read_pdf("933884 cco Saupa 1.pdf",multiple_tables=True,pages='all')
>
> i=1
>
> for table in tables:
>
>     table.to_excel('output'+str(i)+'.xlsx',index=False)
>
>     i=i+1
> ```

For example, when I print the first item of the dataframe obtained from one of these  excel files, named "output_pd":

> ```
> print (output_pd[0][1])
> ```

I obtain:

> ```
> 76) 858000015903708 77) 858000013641969 78)
> ```

The five numbers are in a single column, so I cannot treat them individually.
Is it possible to improve the data handling in these cases?

Answer (score 0):

You could try manually editing the data in excel.  If you use text to columns under the data tab in excel it allows you to split one column into multiple columns without too much work, but you would need to do it for every excel file which could be a pain.

Comment: I have also tried converting the pdf to excel before using it with Python. But it also  has some manual editing, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Have you tried the other extraction method in tabula?  It might give better results.  Other than that I don't really have anything for you.  I had to use tabula a year ago for 35ish huge excel files and had to do a ton of manual editing in excel, which was not fun

Answer (score 0):

Iterating in each item of each column of each dataframe in the list obtained with tabula

```
wrapper.read_pdf(file)
```

in this case

```
tables
```

it is possible to obtain clean data.
In this case:

```
prueba =[]
i = 0
for table in tables:    
    for columna in table.columns:        
        for item in (str(table[columna]).split(" ")):            
            if "858" in str(item):
                prueba.append(item[0:15]) 
print (prueba[0:5])
```

result in:

```
['858000019596025', '858000015903707', '858000013641975', '858000000610864', '858000013428853']
```

But

```
tabula.wrapper.read_pdf
```

does not read the whole initial pdf. 2 values are left in the last page. So, it is still neccesary to manually  make a little edit.